# Ключевое слово this, экземпляр класса и путаница

Tags: java

Читаю в данный момент книгу по Java (ключевое слово `this`), и вот не пойму формулировку:

> Ключевое слово `this` полезно, когда нужно сослаться на экземпляр
>   класса внутри объекта этого класса.

Как я знаю экземпляр класса - это объект.

Как я понял: нужно сослаться на объект класс внутри объекта этого класса. Не очень, не правда ли? Объясните.

А вот и пример сразу после описания ключевого слова `this`.
Где здесь создание объекта я не вижу: `Fish fish = new Fish();`

```
class Fish {
 int currentDepth;

 Fish(int currentDepth){
     this.currentDepth = currentDepth;
 }
}
```

Comment: Вы просто еще не постигли всю мудрость Java(да простят меня приверженцы) =) Вы верно поняли, чтобы обратится к методам\полям объекта внутри объекта нужно использовать this =)
ps. там нет примера создания, но там(в примере) всё верно написано, this.currentDepth - ведет к первому объявлению, тогда как currentDepth ведет к тому что указано в объявлении функции

Comment: Можно мне с подробными примерами кому не трудно и описанием :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> не очень не правда ли?

Всё правильно, когда объекту нужна ссылка на самого себя, приходит на помощь `this`. И ваш пример прекрасно демонстрирует подобную необходимость.

В строке `this.currentDepth = currentDepth;` уже создан новый объект и можно было бы обратиться к полю `currentDepth` объекта, чтобы заполнить его значением из параметра конструктора. Но так уж получилось, что параметр назвали таким же именем, как и поле! И теперь в теле конструктора `currentDepth` - это входящий параметр, а не поле. Так как же добраться до поля? Использовать `this`! А через точку можно получить члены объекта, такие как поле `currentDepth`.

Итак, `this.currentDepth = currentDepth;` - это со стороны объекта значит следующее:

> Присвоить моему полю currentDepth значение параметра currentDepth, которое мне задали в конструкторе

Comment: Пожалуй ваше объяснение менее запутанное нежели мое, но мне проще понимать this как ссылку на объект =) попутно задам вопрос, использование this не является обязательным?(если считать что совпадения имен нет)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я так и написал *"когда объекту нужна ссылка на самого себя"*. Если совпадений нет, то `this` может понадобиться, как минимум, в ещё одном случае --- когда нужно передать ссылку на самого себя куда-либо.

Comment: @Regent извините, но `: ` после *всё правильно* не принимаю

Comment: @4per либо я неправильно представляю себе что вы хотели сказать предложением с "Всё правильно", либо вы против пункта [161а](https://therules.ru/colon/) (он же в первом и третьем пунктах в [этом ответе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/427455/177422)). В любом случае последнее, так сказать, слово за вами

Answer (score 5):

Ответ **4per** верен, но его можно дополнить:

1) В качестве ссылки на тот же самый объект (он же экземпляр), которому принадлежит исполняемый код ("на самого себя" -- недаром для этого в `Delphi` и в некоторых других языках используется слово `self`), `this`может быть использовано не только в конструкторе, но и в любом нестатическом методе (код статических методов не относится ни к какому экземпляру), например

```
  private long count; 
  public String saySomethingAboutThe(int count) {
    return String.format("Значение поля = %d, значение параметра - %d",
                         this.count, // Поле самого объекта 
                         count);     // параметр
  }
```

2) В конструкторах, чтобы не писать один и тот же код несколько раз, можно использовать вызов другого конструктора того же самого класса с использованием того  же ключевого слова `this`:

```
  class MyClass {
    int i = 10, j = -10;  // default values 
    String name;

    // Устанавливает имя, оставляя без изменений дефолтные значения, 
    MyClass(String name) { 
      this.name = "Это класс " + name; 
      // Тут может быть еще какой-нибудь сложный код
    }

    // Устанавливает имя и устанавливает другие значения i и j
    MyClass(String name, int i, int j)  {
      this(name); // Вызов первого конструктора -- он устанавливает имя
                  // и делает еще что надо. 
                  // Должен стоять впереди всего остального кода 
      this.i = i; // И дополнительно меняет значения полей
      this.j = j; 
    }

  }
```

Comment: в c# тоже `this` . `self` в python, pl\sql, например

Comment: @4per да, спасибо. Перепутал с Delphi. Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 0):

**4per** всё правильно написал. Но вот мой ответ.

С помощью `this` ты можешь сослаться на объект(класс) в котором пишешь код. То есть тебе чтобы использовать методы или объекты своего класса где-то внутри своего класса тебе понадобится слово `this`. А в твоём примере `this` конкретизирует какой переменной надо задать значение, т.к. там 2 элемента с одинаковым названием. Если перевести код дословно получится: "переменной `currentDepth` из этого класса задать значение передаваемой в конструктор переменной `currentDepth`".

**P.S.** Я по этой же книжке учился. Очень познавательно, читай до конца!