# Как передать в метод другого класса ссылку на экземпляр текущего класса?

Tags: java, this

Есть `Class1`

```
public class Class1 {

private Class2 class2;

public Class2 getClass2() {
    return class2;
}

public void setClass2(Class2 class2) {
    this.class2 = class2;
}
}
```

Есть `Class2` в котором я имею ссылку на `Class1`. Как при вызове `class1.setClass2();` передать в метод именно ссылку на `class2`?

Я знаю, что можно сделать в `Class2` так: `Class2 c = new Class2();`, и передать в метод `с`, но, как я понимаю, это будет уже новый экземпляр класса, а не текущий, из которого я делаю вызов? Как передать ссылку на самого себя?

Comment: Видимо, нужно изучить использование ключевого слова this

Comment: вы не запутались в постановке вопроса? а то непонятно, что вы хотите передать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ключевое слово this, экземпляр класса и путаница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891753/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-this-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Comment: Если у вас `Class1` содержит ссылку на `Class2`, а `Class2` содержит ссылку на `Class1`, такая ситуация чревата всякими неприятностями. Такого лучше избегать, а если избежать нельзя, то надо очень тщательно продумывать, как это все будет работать, чтобы логическая целостность не нарушалась и утечек памяти не было.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать слово `this`. Слово `this` - это ссылка на объект, в котором оно применяется. 
Вы можете сделать так:

```
//где то в Class2
Class1 cl1 = ...;
cl1.setClass2(this);
```

Можете почитать пару статей на эту тему, например, [эту](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/608-kljuchevoe-slovo-this-v-primerakh).

Кстати, если бы у вас `Class1` наследовался от `Class2`(ну мало ли), то вы могли бы присвоить ссылку переменной таким образом:

```
//где-то в Class1
public void setClass2() {
    class2 = super;
}
```

Потому что слово `super` хранит ссылку на объект-родитель.

---

P.S. Да, тогда это будет уже новый объект:

> Я знаю, что можно сделать в `Class2` так: `Class2 c = new Class2();`,
>   и передать в метод `с`, но, как я понимаю, это будет уже новый
>   экземпляр класса, а не текущий, из которого я делаю вызов?