# this в методе equals()

Tags: java

Разбираюсь с `hashCode()` и `equals()`

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Man {

    private String noseSize;
    private String eyesColor;
    private String haircut;
    private boolean scars;
    private int dnaCode;

    public Man(String noseSize, String eyesColor, String haircut, boolean scars, int dnaCode) {
        this.noseSize = noseSize;
        this.eyesColor = eyesColor;
        this.haircut = haircut;
        this.scars = scars;
        this.dnaCode = dnaCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Man man = (Man) o;
        return dnaCode == man.dnaCode;
    }

    public String getNoseSize() {
        return noseSize;
    }

    public void setNoseSize(String noseSize) {
        this.noseSize = noseSize;
    }

    public String getEyesColor() {
        return eyesColor;
    }

    public void setEyesColor(String eyesColor) {
        this.eyesColor = eyesColor;
    }

    public String getHaircut() {
        return haircut;
    }

    public void setHaircut(String haircut) {
        this.haircut = haircut;
    }

    public boolean isScars() {
        return scars;
    }

    public void setScars(boolean scars) {
        this.scars = scars;
    }

    public int getDnaCode() {
        return dnaCode;
    }

    public void setDnaCode(int dnaCode) {
        this.dnaCode = dnaCode;
    }
}
```

Я вроде бы знаю как работает this, в конструкторе, в сеттере его пишу, но обычно this.что-то, а тут увидел в методе `equals`, `if (this == o) return true;` Не понял на что простой this ссылается?

Comment: Этот вопрос может помочь в понимании `this`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965810/Как-передать-в-метод-другого-класса-ссылку-на-экземпляр-текущего-класса/965825#965825

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` указывает на то же самое что и всегда, на экземпляр класса `Man`

---

Тут происходит сравнение ссылок

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean equals(Object o) {
>     if (this == o) return true;
>     ...
>     return false;
> }
> ```

а смысл выражения `if (this == o) return true;` завершить проверку и вернуть `true` если в метод `equals` передан этот самый объект.

```
Man philipFry = new Man();
Man hubertFarnsworth = new Man(); 

// вот тут сработает проверка равенства ссылок на экземпляры
System.out.println(philipFry.equals(philipFry));        // true

// а тут мы сравниваем 2 разных объекта
System.out.println(philipFry.equals(hubertFarnsworth)); // false
```

Comment: Идеальный пример который вообще мог быть, так еще и быстрый. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван на здоровье, в плане быстрый?)

Comment: Ну обычно я жду минут 15 - 20 чтобы получить такой качественный ответ, иногда вообще 1-2 часа, а тут за 3-5 минут

Comment: Не подскажете случаем, написал в методе equals(Object o) вот такие внутренности   if (this == o) return true; и в итоге пишет missing return statement не пойму из-за чего присутствует же оператор

Comment: Если как в примере выше, то всё четко работает, а если внутри метода оставляем вот такую запись  if (this == o) return true; ,  то ошибку выдает

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван конечно, все ветки выполнения должны возвращать результат, я сейчас подправлю пример

Comment: Странно, оставил в классе метод equals() как у вас в примере и в main(e) написал вот так  System.out.println(man1.equals(man2));  выдаёт false, если делаю System.out.println(man1.equals(woman1)); выдает тоже false, как так?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван а что Вас смущает не пойму

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92937/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).